# replace some chracters in a string by javascript

Tags: javascript

How to replace `"[` by `[` and `"]` by `]`in a string below:
I replace  `"]` by `]` by this code:

```
var str = "[{"propertyid":10000005,"title":"country"}]"
var newstr = str .replace(/\]"/g, ']')
```

But I do not know how to replace `"[` by `[`?

Comment: then it wont be a string anymore! Do you want to convert this string to array?

Comment: please add valid data.

Comment: This can't be a working code, this should be skipped string.

Comment: yes @brk I want to convert it to array then

Comment: hi my friend   i think there's  another way  you can achieve what you want  ,  tell us    what the final purpose of your code to give  answer ,  to restructure your code using different approach

Answer (score 0):

you cannot define a string that way  it will give error

if you want the string that way  you can put the string between  ``

```
var str = `"[{"propertyid":10000005,"title":"country"}]"`
```

but in what scenario you want to use it that way

also  lets say you received string from server or file representing array of objects

like this  `var str = '[{"propertyid":10000005,"title":"country"}]'`

you can use  `arr=JSON.parse(str)`  to  to convert it to a array in memory